# Connection between Google App Engine and Cloud Datastore

Tags: node.js, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCP, just started to develop with node.js in flexible environment.
Since I'm developing the test app.js on local machine, not quite sure that if I can connect the Datastore to fetch the files I saved before(using web console).

I run the file of the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-datastore)(it's about insert data to database and get it), still not sure if this tutorial really connect to the database.
Though it noticed that adding the `@google-cloud/datastore` as a dependency in `package.json`, but it doesn't mention about adding the project ID to any place!

Questions:

1. Can I actually connect to the database(Datastore) while using localhost:8080?
2. If yes, where should I put my project ID?

I tried using like this in my `app.js`:

> const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
>
> const ds = Datastore({   projectId: 'myProjectId' });

but it seems not working as well......

Comment: 1) yes 2) why do you need project id? I'm guessing from a particular project the underlying lib should be able to get the project id from runtime as one project cannot connect to a different datastore

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can connect to the database.  However, I can't answer your second question as I use Java in the flexible runtime, and am completely unfamiliar with Node.js.  I use the gcloud tool, and I log in, and set the project ID in the gcloud tool.  Perhaps you can try that?